# WindowManagerBadTokenException for AccessibilityService Overlay

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating an accessibility service using Xamarin and Visual Studio, following this Codelab (Java + Android SDK): https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/#0

The accessibility service is up and running with it being found in Settings > Accessibility in my android device.

Service:

```
    [Service(Label = "Input Utility", Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindAccessibilityService)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
    [MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/config")]
    public class TapService : AccessibilityService
    {
        FrameLayout mLayout;
        public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
        {
            
        }

        public override void OnInterrupt()
        {
            
        }

        public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
        {
            return base.OnUnbind(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnServiceConnected()
        {
            
            base.OnServiceConnected();

            IWindowManager wm = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
            mLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            WindowManagerLayoutParams lp = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
            lp.Type = WindowManagerTypes.AccessibilityOverlay;
            lp.Format = Format.Translucent;
            lp.Flags |= WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable;
            lp.Width = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
            lp.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
            lp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.InputBar, mLayout);
            wm.AddView(mLayout, lp);

        }
    }
```

Layout File(InputBar.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/power"
        android:text="Power"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/volume_up"
        android:text="Volume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:text="Scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:text="Swipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Metadata file (config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:settingsActivity="true"
   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
   android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
   android:canPerformGestures="true"
   android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```

However I am getting an error when I try to add the overlay to the screen at `wm.AddView(mLayout, lp);`, it gives me this error: `Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException Message=Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`.

I understand that in the official codelab it tells me to launch like so:
[image]

I suspect this may be the source of the error I'm getting, however I am not on android studio, I am using Visual Studio and do not know what to do with this.

To reproduce my error simply clone my github repository, run it, then while it is running, go to the Settings > Accessibility of your android emulator and enable the "Input Service" accessibility service.

Github Repository: https://github.com/tatapuchi/XamarinAccessibilityService

Comment: The **Launch Options** is to set the start up activity. To fix this issue, try getting the LayoutInflater from the system service. Check the code: `IWindowManager wm = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
...
//LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.InputBar, mLayout);
wm.AddView(mLayout, lp);`

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT I tried using that code but I am still getting the same error message, should I change the startup activity or something? I'm unaware how to go about this (setting MainActivity MainLauncher to false makes the application not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this function, please mark sure the `Settings.CanDrawOverlays` has been enabled. Try detect the status before starting the service.

```
using Android.Provider;
...

if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
{
    StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + PackageName)), 0);
}
else
{
    StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(DemoService)));
}

...
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(DemoService)));
        }
    }
}
```

### Update:

Here is the related code about the sample:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public AccessibilityServiceBinder binder;
    public AccessibilityServiceConnection accessibilityServiceConnection;
    public bool isBound = false;
    bool isBoundAC = false;
    Intent ServiceIntent;

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        if (!isBoundAC)
        {
            accessibilityServiceConnection = new AccessibilityServiceConnection(this);
            isBoundAC = BindService(ServiceIntent, accessibilityServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            if (isBoundAC)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "AccessibilityService is Bound", ToastLength.Long);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(TapService));
        ServiceIntent.SetPackage("com.companyname.app19_3_1");

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn).Click += async delegate
        {
            if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
            {
                StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + PackageName)), 0);
            }
        };
    }
}

public class AccessibilityServiceBinder : Binder
{
    TapService service;
    public AccessibilityServiceBinder(TapService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
    public TapService GetAccessibilityService()
    {
        return service;
    }
}

public class AccessibilityServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    MainActivity activity;
    AccessibilityServiceBinder binder;
    public AccessibilityServiceBinder Binder
    {
        get
        {
            return (AccessibilityServiceBinder)binder;
        }
    }
    public AccessibilityServiceConnection(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        var accessibilityServiceBinder = service as AccessibilityServiceBinder;
        if (accessibilityServiceBinder != null)
        {
            activity.binder = accessibilityServiceBinder;
            activity.isBound = true;
            this.binder = accessibilityServiceBinder;
        }
    }
    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        activity.isBound = false;
    }
}


[Service(Label = "Input Utility", Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindAccessibilityService, Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
[MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/config")]
public class TapService : AccessibilityService
{
    FrameLayout mLayout;
    ...
    protected override void OnServiceConnected()
    {
        base.OnServiceConnected();

        IWindowManager wm = GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        WindowManagerLayoutParams lp = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
        lp.Type = WindowManagerTypes.AccessibilityOverlay;
        lp.Format = Format.Translucent;
        lp.Flags |= WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable;
        lp.Width = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
        lp.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
        lp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layoutfloat, null);
        wm.AddView(view, lp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what "Settings" is in here, I cannot find the correct using directive for it, also I don't explicitly start the service like that, I think its done entirely by the attributes, because the TapService class and my Metadata file is all there is. I haven't even added anything to my MainActivity :( . I can't find the using directive for StartActivityForResult either :/ .

Comment: The 'Settings' parameter is from the Android.Provider library, add the `using Android.Provider;` namespace to use the method. And I've updated the code, please check that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. I followed the steps, adding the using directive and placed the first bit in my OnCreate() directly before LoadApplication(); is called. I also added the second bit into my OnRequestPermissionsResult(); now when I start I am prompted to this "Display over other apps" system page. However this page continues to load endlessly and does nothing, when I go to Settings > Accessibility to enable my service, I get the same error. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tested function in a normal sevice, so I use the 'ApplicationOverlay' type instead. Try to use this type to test in your project.

Comment: This now leads me to the same "Display over other apps" system page, but it just shows some apps that are allowed to display over other apps. Morever, my actual accessibility service will only be launched when I go to Settings > Accessibility and enable it. This leads to the same exception being thrown, regardless of code in MainActivity. I will try and create a github repo with my code in it so reproduction of the error is easy.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add the git, to reproduce, copy paste the TapService file into the android project, add an xml folder to the android project and paste the metadata file into there. To start up the accessibility service, run, go out of app and go into settings > accessibility and enable it. You may also need to add the layout xml file into the Layout folder, which i will be including in my question shortly.

Comment: I have created a github repo, to reproduce my error simply clone it, run, go into the settings > accessibility of your android emulator and enable 'Input Service': https://github.com/tatapuchi/XamarinAccessibilityService

Comment: Thanks for sharing the related code, I'm testing the WindowManger in the AccessibilityService and will update here later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226610/discussion-between-0xb01b-and-jarvan-zhang-msft).

Comment: Could it be that this is some bug within Xamarin.Android? As the accessibility services function but the overlays don't?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested the AccessibilityService on my side, the overlay works fines with both the `AccessibilityOverlay` type and `ApplicationOverlay` type. Did you add the `android:settingsActivity` tag in the config.xml? Try adding the code for test.

Comment: Hi Jarvan, I added `android:settingsActivity="true"` to config.xml, but i'm getting the same error, could you push to code to the sample repo so I can check it out?

Comment: I've updated the code, you could check that.

Comment: could you upload this to github or a zip file so that I can clone it directly? I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on because I think you have a Xamarin.Android project while I am working on my Xamarin.Forms Android project

Comment: I don't understand what `Resource.Id.btn` is in this case, also I was actually using the Android project in a Xamarin.Forms application so I didn't have `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);` but I have made a Xamarin.Android application as well and without the `Resource.Id.btn` code it worked well in both projects, thank you very much for your time and help.